# How can I solve this Sphinx search dependency issue?

Tags: linux, terminal, installation, sphinx

I'm trying to install [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com) search on a CentOS VPS via SSH but I keep getting dependency issues that I can't seem to resolve.

Here's the OS I'm using:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS 6.4 (Final)

uname -a
Linux host.example.com 2.6.32-042stab074.10 #1 SMP Fri Mar 1 09:18:44 MSK 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

This to me looks like I need the 32-bit CentOS 6 rpm so I tried to install it with this command:

```
sudo yum install http://sphinxsearch.com/files/sphinx-2.0.8-1.rhel6.i386.rpm
```

but I get the following error message:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.advancedhosters.com
 * extras: centos.mirror.constant.com
 * updates: mirror.lug.udel.edu
base                                                                                                                                                                      | 3.7 kB     00:00     
extras                                                                                                                                                                    | 3.5 kB     00:00     
updates                                                                                                                                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
sphinx-2.0.8-1.rhel6.i386.rpm                                                                                                                                             | 5.6 MB     00:30     
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-oMekz6/sphinx-2.0.8-1.rhel6.i386.rpm: sphinx-2.0.8-1.rhel6.i386
Marking /var/tmp/yum-root-oMekz6/sphinx-2.0.8-1.rhel6.i386.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package sphinx.i386 0:2.0.8-1.rhel6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16 for package: sphinx-2.0.8-1.rhel6.i386
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16) for package: sphinx-2.0.8-1.rhel6.i386
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: sphinx-2.0.8-1.rhel6.i386 (/sphinx-2.0.8-1.rhel6.i386)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16
Error: Package: sphinx-2.0.8-1.rhel6.i386 (/sphinx-2.0.8-1.rhel6.i386)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 2 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
frontpage-2002-SR1.2.i386 has missing requires of libexpat.so.0
sendmail-cf-8.14.4-8.el6.noarch has missing requires of sendmail = ('0', '8.14.4', '8.el6')
```

No matter what I try I always seem to be missing `libmysqlclient.so.16`.

Any idea where I can find this package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yum install mysql-devel
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Install the remi repository:

[http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en]

Enterprise Linux 6 (with EPEL) i386 or x86_64

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm

rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm epel-release-6*.rpm
```

then install compat-mysql51

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install compat-mysql51
```

then install sphinx from the rpm downloaded

```
yum localinstall sphinx-2.1.2-1.rhel6.SYSTEM-VERSION.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the SphinxSearch docker files ([docker hub link](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/leodido/sphinxsearch)) to easily install SphinxSearch.

Grab it:

```
docker pull leodido/sphinxsearch:latest
```

If you want to see how to **compile from source** (which I recommend as the better mode to install SphinxSearch), look into them - e.g., [here](https://github.com/leodido/dockerfiles/blob/master/sphinxsearch:2.2.9/Dockerfile).